# GParted error while expanding file system "Error fsyncing/closing /dev/sdb1: Input/output error"

Tags: data-recovery, gparted

My expansion Hard disk is having error and some data is lost/corrupted.
I was using GParted to expand a partition. I got this error "Error fsyncing/closing /dev/sdb1: Input/output error".

I have uploaded the Gparted error log at following link:
http://pastebin.com/qMy0VE6a

I tried both Gparted & testdisk to recover data or partition but failed.

Please help to recover my data.

Comment: please use `pastebin` for log instead.

Comment: Tried pastebin earlier but the log file is larger than 512kb. I don't have pro account.

Comment: you can try to snip the logs and just share the relevant one.

Comment: thanks for guidance. uploaded the significant parts of logs to pastebin.

Comment: looks like the filesystem was corrupted. do `e2fsck`.

Comment: but I am able to see the original partition with some files missing as expansion failed.  Should I create a new partition in free space & perform file recovery there?

Comment: you can try to fix the filesystem first. If still no good then you can do the recovery like you have mentioned.

Comment: sorry got busy, will try this today and post results.. thanks a lot for your suggestions..

Comment: Nothing helped...   Just formatted the HDD..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A message such as "Error fsyncing/closing /dev/sdb1: Input/output error" often indicates a hardware problem.  This can be as simple as a loose cable, or as serious as a failing drive.

When the error occurs, you can check the output of the **dmesg** command for any additional details.

Also some hard drives include smart monitoring.  You might try using **gsmartcontrol** to see if there are any indications of poor health for the drive.

Answer (score 3):

I got this error on a fairly new and good working drive. It took me ages to realize I had a hard drive password set on the drive on a newer machine and I was using the drive on an older desktop that didn't support the same HD encryption.

Solution? Put it back in the newer machine,  remove the HD password in the BIOS and everything works great.

Comment: I love you.....