# GParted Error fsyncing/closing

Tags: hard-drive, gparted

I came across [this AskUbuntu thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/684993/gparted-error-while-expanding-file-system-error-fsyncing-closing-dev-sdb1-inp) while searching for a solution to problems with an old SATA drive.
I tried `dmesg` on the problem drive and got the following [(Complete copy  on PasteBin)](https://pastebin.com/nZ6177MV):

```
[    4.755793] hub 8-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    4.755802] hub 8-0:1.0: 2 ports detected
[    4.755956] ahci 0000:00:1f.2: version 3.0
[    4.756182] ahci 0000:00:1f.2: SSS flag set, parallel bus scan disabled
[    4.756211] ahci 0000:00:1f.2: AHCI 0001.0200 32 slots 4 ports 3 Gbps 0x33 impl SATA mode
[    4.756214] ahci 0000:00:1f.2: flags: 64bit ncq sntf stag pm led clo pmp pio slum part ccc ems 
[    4.780937] scsi host2: ahci
[    4.781085] scsi host3: ahci
[    4.781216] scsi host4: ahci
[    4.781359] scsi host5: ahci
[    4.781498] scsi host6: ahci
[    4.781633] scsi host7: ahci
[    4.781706] ata3: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0xfa206000 port 0xfa206100 irq 29
[    4.781708] ata4: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0xfa206000 port 0xfa206180 irq 29
[    4.781710] ata5: DUMMY
[    4.781711] ata6: DUMMY
[    4.781713] ata7: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0xfa206000 port 0xfa206300 irq 29
[    4.781715] ata8: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0xfa206000 port 0xfa206380 irq 29
[    4.791917] ahci 0000:03:00.0: AHCI 0001.0000 32 slots 2 ports 3 Gbps 0x3 impl SATA mode
[    4.791921] ahci 0000:03:00.0: flags: 64bit ncq pm led clo pmp pio slum part 
[    4.792350] scsi host8: ahci
[    4.792478] scsi host9: ahci
[    4.792549] ata9: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m8192@0xfa000000 port 0xfa000100 irq 19
[    4.792552] ata10: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m8192@0xfa000000 port 0xfa000180 irq 19
[    4.800043] firewire_ohci 0000:05:00.2: added OHCI v1.10 device as card 0, 4 IR + 8 IT contexts, quirks 0x2
[    4.884017] tsc: Refined TSC clocksource calibration: 2666.666 MHz
[    4.884022] clocksource: tsc: mask: 0xffffffffffffffff max_cycles: 0x26703cd6786, max_idle_ns: 440795256025 ns
[    5.048015] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci-pci
[    5.064017] usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci-pci
[    5.090545] ata3: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[    5.100676] ata10: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[    5.102254] ata9: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[    5.188673] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=05ac, idProduct=1006
[    5.188677] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[    5.188679] usb 1-1: Product: Keyboard Hub
[    5.188682] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: Apple, Inc.
[    5.188684] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: 000000000000
[    5.188969] hub 1-1:1.0: USB hub found
[    5.189040] hub 1-1:1.0: 3 ports detected
[    5.196548] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=1a40, idProduct=0101
[    5.196552] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
[    5.196555] usb 2-1: Product: USB 2.0 Hub
[    5.196983] hub 2-1:1.0: USB hub found
[    5.197059] hub 2-1:1.0: 4 ports detected
[    5.300105] firewire_core 0000:05:00.2: created device fw0: GUID 00023c002101a5c9, S400
[    5.428014] usb 3-2: new low-speed USB device number 2 using uhci_hcd
[    5.460015] usb 1-1.2: new low-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[    5.468014] usb 2-1.1: new high-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[    5.556018] ata4: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[    5.558544] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=05ac, idProduct=0250
[    5.558548] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    5.558550] usb 1-1.2: Product: Apple Keyboard
[    5.558552] usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: Apple Inc.
[    5.562535] hidraw: raw HID events driver (C) Jiri Kosina
[    5.569351] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[    5.569353] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[    5.571718] input: Apple Inc. Apple Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.7/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2:1.0/0003:05AC:0250.0001/input/input2
[    5.584728] ata4.00: ATA-8: ST31500341AS, CC1H, max UDMA/133
[    5.584732] ata4.00: 2930277168 sectors, multi 0: LBA48 NCQ (depth 31/32)
[    5.624265] apple 0003:05AC:0250.0001: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Apple Inc. Apple Keyboard] on usb-0000:00:1a.7-1.2/input0
[    5.625363] input: Apple Inc. Apple Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.7/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2:1.1/0003:05AC:0250.0002/input/input3
[    5.626619] ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133
[    5.626812] scsi 3:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      ST31500341AS     CC1H PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[    5.637800] usb 2-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=090c, idProduct=1000
[    5.637803] usb 2-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[    5.637806] usb 2-1.1: Product: Flash Disk
[    5.637808] usb 2-1.1: Manufacturer: USB
[    5.637811] usb 2-1.1: SerialNumber: FBG1207170361410
[    5.641522] usb-storage 2-1.1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[    5.641613] scsi host10: usb-storage 2-1.1:1.0
[    5.641700] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[    5.643095] usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
[    5.680076] apple 0003:05AC:0250.0002: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Device [Apple Inc. Apple Keyboard] on usb-0000:00:1a.7-1.2/input1
[    5.724017] usb 2-1.4: new full-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[    5.814037] usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=045e, idProduct=0734
[    5.814041] usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    5.814044] usb 3-2: Product: Microsoft® Wireless Receiver 700 v2.0
[    5.814046] usb 3-2: Manufacturer: Liteon
[    5.850428] usb 2-1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=0a12, idProduct=0001
[    5.850432] usb 2-1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    5.850434] usb 2-1.4: Product: CSR8510 A10
[    5.858270] input: Liteon Microsoft® Wireless Receiver 700 v2.0 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.0/0003:045E:0734.0003/input/input4
[    5.884074] clocksource: Switched to clocksource tsc
[    5.912196] hid-generic 0003:045E:0734.0003: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Liteon Microsoft® Wireless Receiver 700 v2.0] on usb-0000:00:1a.0-2/input0
[    5.912905] input: Liteon Microsoft® Wireless Receiver 700 v2.0 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.1/0003:045E:0734.0004/input/input5
[    5.966185] ata7: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[    5.968108] hid-generic 0003:045E:0734.0004: input,hidraw3: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Liteon Microsoft® Wireless Receiver 700 v2.0] on usb-0000:00:1a.0-2/input1
[    6.274161] ata8: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[    6.279808] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] 2930277168 512-byte logical blocks: (1.50 TB/1.36 TiB)
[    6.279851] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[    6.279853] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
[    6.279871] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[    6.294620]  sda: sda1 < sda5 >
[    6.294939] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
[    6.595824] Atheros(R) L2 Ethernet Driver - version 2.2.3
[    6.595828] Copyright (c) 2007 Atheros Corporation.
[    6.632510] pps_core: LinuxPPS API ver. 1 registered
[    6.632513] pps_core: Software ver. 5.3.6 - Copyright 2005-2007 Rodolfo Giometti <giometti@linux.it>
[    6.633799] PTP clock support registered
[    6.644185] bnx2x: QLogic 5771x/578xx 10/20-Gigabit Ethernet Driver bnx2x 1.712.30-0 (2014/02/10)
[    6.696045] device-mapper: uevent: version 1.0.3
[    6.708074] device-mapper: ioctl: 4.34.0-ioctl (2015-10-28) initialised: dm-devel@redhat.com
[    6.719470] md: linear personality registered for level -1
[    6.721682] md: multipath personality registered for level -4
[    6.723807] md: raid0 personality registered for level 0
[    6.726378] md: raid1 personality registered for level 1
[    6.824026] raid6: mmxx1    gen()  3523 MB/s
[    6.868585] scsi 10:0:0:0: Direct-Access     USB      Flash Disk       1100 PQ: 0 ANSI: 4
[    6.892020] raid6: mmxx2    gen()  3923 MB/s
[    6.960012] raid6: sse1x1   gen()  2381 MB/s
[    7.028019] raid6: sse1x2   gen()  3116 MB/s
[    7.096029] raid6: sse2x1   gen()  4366 MB/s
[    7.164008] raid6: sse2x1   xor()  4604 MB/s
[    7.232021] raid6: sse2x2   gen()  5170 MB/s
[    7.300010] raid6: sse2x2   xor()  5576 MB/s
[    7.300011] raid6: using algorithm sse2x2 gen() 5170 MB/s
[    7.300012] raid6: .... xor() 5576 MB/s, rmw enabled
[    7.300014] raid6: using ssse3x1 recovery algorithm
[    7.300939] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] 3915776 512-byte logical blocks: (2.00 GB/1.87 GiB)
[    7.301316] xor: measuring software checksum speed
[    7.301685] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[    7.301688] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
[    7.302454] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[    7.302492] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[    7.306811]  sdb: sdb1
[    7.309552] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[    7.340008]    pIII_sse  :  9840.000 MB/sec
[    7.380008]    prefetch64-sse: 11157.000 MB/sec
[    7.380010] xor: using function: prefetch64-sse (11157.000 MB/sec)
[    7.381154] async_tx: api initialized (async)
[    7.388459] md: raid6 personality registered for level 6
[    7.388461] md: raid5 personality registered for level 5
[    7.388462] md: raid4 personality registered for level 4
[    7.393638] md: raid10 personality registered for level 10
[    7.695123] loop: module loaded
[    7.980020] squashfs: version 4.0 (2009/01/31) Phillip Lougher
[    8.033399] overlayfs: missing 'workdir'
[    8.601819] random: nonblocking pool is initialized
[    9.647765] ip_tables: (C) 2000-2006 Netfilter Core Team
[    9.701688] systemd[1]: systemd 231 running in system mode. (+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ -LZ4 +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD +IDN)
[    9.701831] systemd[1]: Detected architecture x86.
[    9.718955] systemd[1]: Set hostname to <localhost.localdomain>.
[    9.719349] systemd[1]: Initializing machine ID from random generator.
[   10.060375] systemd[1]: Started Dispatch Password Requests to Console Directory Watch.
[   10.060433] systemd[1]: Listening on udev Kernel Socket.
[   10.060469] systemd[1]: Listening on LVM2 metadata daemon socket.
[   10.060603] systemd[1]: Set up automount Arbitrary Executable File Formats File System Automount Point.
[   10.060633] systemd[1]: Listening on LVM2 poll daemon socket.
[   10.060668] systemd[1]: Listening on udev Control Socket.
[   10.060710] systemd[1]: Started Forward Password Requests to Wall Directory Watch.
[   10.060749] systemd[1]: Listening on Journal Socket (/dev/log).
[   10.060763] systemd[1]: Reached target Paths.
[   10.060798] systemd[1]: Listening on Device-mapper event daemon FIFOs.
[   10.060838] systemd[1]: Listening on Journal Socket.
[   10.060857] systemd[1]: Reached target Encrypted Volumes.
[   10.060888] systemd[1]: Listening on /dev/initctl Compatibility Named Pipe.
[   10.060901] systemd[1]: Reached target Swap.
[   10.060997] systemd[1]: Created slice User and Session Slice.
[   10.061069] systemd[1]: Listening on Journal Audit Socket.
[   10.061143] systemd[1]: Created slice System Slice.
[   10.080171] systemd[1]: Starting Create list of required static device nodes for the current kernel...
[   10.080200] systemd[1]: Started live-tools - System Support Scripts.
[   10.080865] systemd[1]: Starting Set the console keyboard layout...
[   10.084058] systemd[1]: Starting Load Kernel Modules...
[   10.084611] systemd[1]: Starting live-config contains the components that configure a live system during the boot process (late userspace)....
[   10.085129] systemd[1]: Starting Monitoring of LVM2 mirrors, snapshots etc. using dmeventd or progress polling...
[   10.085685] systemd[1]: Mounting Huge Pages File System...
[   10.085705] systemd[1]: Reached target Slices.
[   10.087106] systemd[1]: Starting Remount Root and Kernel File Systems...
[   10.087653] systemd[1]: Mounting Debug File System...
[   10.088276] systemd[1]: Mounting POSIX Message Queue File System...
[   10.088818] systemd[1]: Starting Journal Service...
[   10.088922] systemd[1]: Created slice system-getty.slice.
[   10.298409] systemd[1]: Started Create list of required static device nodes for the current kernel.
[   10.440183] systemd[1]: Starting Create Static Device Nodes in /dev...
[   10.511025] systemd[1]: Mounted POSIX Message Queue File System.
[   10.513471] systemd[1]: Mounted Debug File System.
[   10.513511] systemd[1]: Mounted Huge Pages File System.
[   10.513780] systemd[1]: Started Remount Root and Kernel File Systems.
[   10.575669] systemd[1]: Starting udev Coldplug all Devices...
[   10.576602] systemd[1]: Starting Load/Save Random Seed...
[   10.602473] systemd[1]: Started LVM2 metadata daemon.
[   10.735641] fuse init (API version 7.25)
[   10.806012] systemd[1]: Started Load/Save Random Seed.
[   10.928239] systemd[1]: Started udev Coldplug all Devices.
[   10.995223] systemd[1]: Started Journal Service.
[   11.035982] systemd-journald[450]: Received request to flush runtime journal from PID 1
[   11.419947] SGI XFS with ACLs, security attributes, realtime, no debug enabled
[   12.056034] JFS: nTxBlock = 8192, nTxLock = 65536
[   12.189156] Loading iSCSI transport class v2.0-870.
[   12.290276] iscsi: registered transport (tcp)
[   12.604081] iscsi: registered transport (iser)
[   19.931453] input: Power Button as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input6
[   19.931459] ACPI: Power Button [PWRB]
[   19.931541] input: Power Button as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input7
[   19.931544] ACPI: Power Button [PWRF]
[   20.049337] shpchp: Standard Hot Plug PCI Controller Driver version: 0.4
[   20.052585] parport_pc 00:04: reported by Plug and Play ACPI
[   20.052653] parport0: PC-style at 0x378, irq 7 [PCSPP,TRISTATE]
[   20.580212] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000428-0x000000000000042F conflicts with OpRegion 0x000000000000042C-0x000000000000042D (\GP2C) (20160422/utaddress-255)
[   20.580220] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
[   20.580254] lpc_ich: Resource conflict(s) found affecting gpio_ich
[   20.680592] sd 3:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[   20.680637] sd 10:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[   20.684964] i801_smbus 0000:00:1f.3: SMBus using PCI interrupt
[   20.833342] gameport gameport0: EMU10K1 is pci0000:05:00.1/gameport0, io 0xd100, speed 1028kHz
[   20.913527] input: PC Speaker as /devices/platform/pcspkr/input/input8
[   21.021706] [drm] Initialized drm 1.1.0 20060810
[   21.519937] wmi: Mapper loaded
[   21.804646] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: NVIDIA G92 (092a00a2)
[   21.804652] pmd_set_huge: Cannot satisfy [mem 0xf6000000-0xf6200000] with a huge-page mapping due to MTRR override.
[   21.864795] ppdev: user-space parallel port driver
[   21.911978] iTCO_vendor_support: vendor-support=0
[   21.913336] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bios: version 62.92.6d.00.07
[   21.934125] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fb: 1024 MiB GDDR3
[   21.985429] kvm: disabled by bios
[   21.989054] [TTM] Zone  kernel: Available graphics memory: 410932 kiB
[   21.989058] [TTM] Zone highmem: Available graphics memory: 4148984 kiB
[   21.989059] [TTM] Initializing pool allocator
[   21.989066] [TTM] Initializing DMA pool allocator
[   21.989085] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: VRAM: 1024 MiB
[   21.989087] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: GART: 1048576 MiB
[   21.989092] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: TMDS table version 2.0
[   21.989094] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: DCB version 4.0
[   21.989097] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: DCB outp 00: 02000300 00000028
[   21.989099] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: DCB outp 01: 01000302 00020030
[   21.989101] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: DCB outp 02: 04011310 00020028
[   21.989103] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: DCB outp 03: 02022322 00020010
[   21.989105] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: DCB conn 00: 00000100
[   21.989107] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: DCB conn 01: 00001030
[   21.989109] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: DCB conn 02: 00002261
[   22.015239] [drm] Supports vblank timestamp caching Rev 2 (21.10.2013).
[   22.015242] [drm] Driver supports precise vblank timestamp query.
[   22.028948] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.21
[   22.028966] NET: Registered protocol family 31
[   22.028967] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   22.028972] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   22.028974] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   22.028980] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   22.046811] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: MM: using CRYPT for buffer copies
[   22.054005] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D2: autoconfig for ALC889A: line_outs=4 (0x14/0x15/0x16/0x17/0x0) type:line
[   22.054008] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D2:    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[   22.054011] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D2:    hp_outs=1 (0x1b/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[   22.054012] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D2:    mono: mono_out=0x0
[   22.054014] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D2:    dig-out=0x1e/0x0
[   22.054016] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D2:    inputs:
[   22.054018] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D2:      Rear Mic=0x18
[   22.054020] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D2:      Front Mic=0x19
[   22.054022] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D2:      Line=0x1a
[   22.054023] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D2:      CD=0x1c
[   22.054025] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D2:    dig-in=0x1f
[   22.084141] input: HDA Digital PCBeep as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input9
[   22.085676] input: HDA Intel Rear Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input10
[   22.085750] input: HDA Intel Front Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input11
[   22.085820] input: HDA Intel Line as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input12
[   22.085893] input: HDA Intel Line Out Front as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input13
[   22.085963] input: HDA Intel Line Out Surround as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input14
[   22.086034] input: HDA Intel Line Out CLFE as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input15
[   22.086106] input: HDA Intel Line Out Side as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input16
[   22.086635] iTCO_wdt: Intel TCO WatchDog Timer Driver v1.11
[   22.086677] iTCO_wdt: Found a ICH9 TCO device (Version=2, TCOBASE=0x0460)
[   22.086766] iTCO_wdt: initialized. heartbeat=30 sec (nowayout=0)
[   22.139690] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: allocated 1920x1080 fb: 0x70000, bo ee424000
[   22.139785] fbcon: nouveaufb (fb0) is primary device
[   22.243512] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 200x56
[   22.245256] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fb0: nouveaufb frame buffer device
[   22.305856] usbcore: registered new interface driver btusb
[   22.308027] [drm] Initialized nouveau 1.3.1 20120801 for 0000:01:00.0 on minor 0
[   22.395831] intel_powerclamp: No package C-state available
[   22.464368] intel_powerclamp: No package C-state available
[   22.628464] intel_powerclamp: No package C-state available
[   22.797924] intel_powerclamp: No package C-state available
[   40.957236] systemd[1]: apt-daily.timer: Adding 8h 20min 44.623520s random time.
[   44.220090] Btrfs loaded, crc32c=crc32c-generic
[   44.220094] BTRFS: selftest: sectorsize: 4096  nodesize: 4096
[   44.220096] BTRFS: selftest: sectorsize: 4096  nodesize: 8192
[   44.220098] BTRFS: selftest: sectorsize: 4096  nodesize: 16384
[   44.220099] BTRFS: selftest: sectorsize: 4096  nodesize: 32768
[   44.220101] BTRFS: selftest: sectorsize: 4096  nodesize: 65536
[   44.776020] NILFS version 2 loaded
[   52.932366] ata4.00: READ LOG DMA EXT failed, trying unqueued
[   52.971942] ata4: failed to read log page 10h (errno=-5)
[   52.971947] ata4.00: exception Emask 0x1 SAct 0xc0000 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[   52.971949] ata4.00: irq_stat 0x40000001
[   52.971952] ata4.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[   52.971958] ata4.00: cmd 60/00:90:b3:ce:04/01:00:00:00:00/40 tag 18 ncq 131072 in
                        res 41/04:98:b3:cf:04/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x1 (device error)
[   52.971961] ata4.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[   52.971963] ata4.00: error: { ABRT }
[   52.971965] ata4.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[   52.971970] ata4.00: cmd 60/00:98:b3:cf:04/01:00:00:00:00/40 tag 19 ncq 131072 in
                        res 41/04:98:b3:cf:04/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x1 (device error)
[   52.971973] ata4.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[   52.971975] ata4.00: error: { ABRT }
[   53.021907] ata4.00: both IDENTIFYs aborted, assuming NODEV
[   53.021909] ata4.00: revalidation failed (errno=-2)
[   53.021912] ata4: hard resetting link
[   53.488014] ata4: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[   53.513272] ata4.00: both IDENTIFYs aborted, assuming NODEV
[   53.513274] ata4.00: revalidation failed (errno=-2)
[   58.488015] ata4: hard resetting link
[   58.956015] ata4: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[   58.993223] ata4.00: both IDENTIFYs aborted, assuming NODEV
[   58.993227] ata4.00: revalidation failed (errno=-2)
[   58.993229] ata4.00: disabled
[   58.993250] ata4: EH complete
[   58.993275] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#20 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[   58.993282] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#22 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[   58.993287] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#20 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 04 cf b3 00 01 00 00
[   58.993289] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#22 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 ae a8 65 03 00 01 00 00
[   58.993291] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 2930271491
[   58.993297] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 315315
[   58.993319] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#21 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[   58.993323] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#21 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 04 ce b3 00 01 00 00
[   58.993326] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 315059
[   58.993394] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#23 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[   58.993398] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#23 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 ae a8 65 03 00 00 01 00
[   58.993399] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 2930271491
[   58.993402] Buffer I/O error on dev sda5, logical block 2930255360, async page read
[   58.993407] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#24 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[   58.993409] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#24 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 ae a8 65 04 00 00 01 00
[   58.993411] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 2930271492
[   58.993413] Buffer I/O error on dev sda5, logical block 2930255361, async page read
[   58.993418] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#25 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[   58.993421] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#25 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 ae a8 65 05 00 00 01 00
[   58.993422] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 2930271493
[   58.993424] Buffer I/O error on dev sda5, logical block 2930255362, async page read
[   58.993428] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#26 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[   58.993430] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#26 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 ae a8 65 06 00 00 01 00
[   58.993432] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 2930271494
[   58.993433] Buffer I/O error on dev sda5, logical block 2930255363, async page read
[   58.993437] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#27 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[   58.993439] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#27 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 ae a8 65 07 00 00 01 00
[   58.993441] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 2930271495
[   58.993442] Buffer I/O error on dev sda5, logical block 2930255364, async page read
[   58.993446] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#28 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[   58.993448] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#28 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 ae a8 65 08 00 00 01 00
[   58.993450] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 2930271496
[   58.993451] Buffer I/O error on dev sda5, logical block 2930255365, async page read
[   58.993455] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#29 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[   58.993458] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#29 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 ae a8 65 09 00 00 01 00
[   58.993459] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 2930271497
[   58.993461] Buffer I/O error on dev sda5, logical block 2930255366, async page read
[   58.993464] Buffer I/O error on dev sda5, logical block 2930255367, async page read
[   58.995552] Buffer I/O error on dev sda5, logical block 2930255744, async page read
[   58.995569] Buffer I/O error on dev sda5, logical block 2930255745, async page read
root@debian:~# t
```

This drive has been giving problems for a while, but at 1.5GB I'd really like to have a look at what's on there before binning it!

Comment: Specifically, what is your question?

Comment: Is there anything in the dmesg that can help me recover it to at least check what's on it and maybe recover some files?

Comment: Status please...

Comment: Status please...

Answer (score 0):

**RECOVERY:**

Boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, and you **might** be able to view/recover what's on the disk (/dev/sda5), and copy files off to another disk drive.

---

You may be having either/both NCQ errors or bad blocks (or just a failed HDD).

```
[   52.971965] ata4.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[   52.971970] ata4.00: cmd 60/00:98:b3:cf:04/01:00:00:00:00/40 tag 19 ncq 131072 in
                        res 41/04:98:b3:cf:04/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x1 (device error)
```

**NCQ:**

Native Command Queuing (NCQ) is an extension of the Serial ATA protocol allowing hard disk drives to internally optimize the order in which received read and write commands are executed.

Edit `/etc/default/grub` and change the following line to include this extra parameter. Then do `sudo update-grub` to write the changes to disk. Reboot. Monitor hangs, and watch `/var/log/syslog` or `dmesg` for continued error messages.

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash libata.force=noncq"

---

**BAD BLOCKING:**

Note: do NOT abort a bad block scan!

Note: do NOT bad block a SSD

Note: backup your important files FIRST!

Note: this will take many hours

Note: you may have a pending HDD failure

Boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB.

In `terminal`...

`sudo fdisk -l` # identify all "Linux Filesystem" partitions

`sudo e2fsck -fcky /dev/sdXX` # read-only test

or

`sudo e2fsck -fccky /dev/sdXX` # non-destructive read/write test **(recommended)**

The -k is important, because it saves the previous bad block table, and adds any new bad blocks to that table. Without -k, you loose all of the prior bad block information.

The -fccky parameter...

```
   -f    Force checking even if the file system seems clean.

   -c    This option causes e2fsck to use badblocks(8) program  to  do  a
         read-only  scan  of  the device in order to find any bad blocks.
         If any bad blocks are found, they are added  to  the  bad  block
         inode  to  prevent them from being allocated to a file or direc‐
         tory.  If this option is specified twice,  then  the  bad  block
         scan will be done using a non-destructive read-write test.

   -k    When combined with the -c option, any existing bad blocks in the
         bad blocks list are preserved, and any new bad blocks  found  by
         running  badblocks(8)  will  be added to the existing bad blocks
         list.

   -y    Assume  an answer of `yes' to all questions; allows e2fsck to be
         used non-interactively.  This option may not be specified at the
         same time as the -n or -p options.
```